# unobtrusive validation don't working in a partial view

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to make validation client in a partial view:

**My Partial View**

```
    <form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="col-md-offset-4">Create a new activity</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body col-md-offset-1">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="col-md-2 control-label validator"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control required" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-default col-md-2 col-md-offset-4">Cancel</a>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default col-md-2" data-loading-text="..." />                
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                $("form").removeData("validator");
                $("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
        </script>  
    }
```

It doesn't work. Also, i don't found an error in the browser's console.

Have u an idea ? Please tell me if i forget something.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your can do validation in the partial view but the scripts should be added in the main view not in the partial view

also looks like you have something in your scripts to remove the validation from the form which should not be there

Comment: It's Ok now, i added the javascript file in my _Layout file.

Comment: Joe Audette can u tell me, please, where i should put validation form ? and if u have example please ?